# how do I create and assign a new object to a user after sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do you create and assign a new object to the User after a sign up with devise?

I created a Profile model to hold attributes for the User model such as "name" "location" "description" "photo" etc.

I'm using Devise to register users for the User model, which will just hold email and password.

I wanted to separate these attributes out from one User model so user profile attributes can be updated without a password.

I've tried an after_create callback to initialize a new profile object, but it doesn't work.

"undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #"

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base      
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :setup_profile

  protected

  def setup_profile
    @profile = current_user.profile.create
  end
end
```

my_devise/registrations_controller.rb

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource(registration_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      #clean_up_passwords
      respond_with resource
    end
  end 

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute
      # update_without_password doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  # check if we need password to update user data
  # ie if password or email was changed
  # extend this as needed

  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
      params[:user][:password].present? ||
      params[:user][:password_confirmation].present?
  end
    # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password
  def needs_pass?(user, params)
    params[:password].present?
  end

  def registration_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :location, :description, :website)
  end

  protected 
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    current_user
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current user` is not available in model. And when you use callback you are actually referring to that object that you work with (the user that signs up).

```
  after_create :setup_profile

  def setup_profile
    profile = self.create_profile # or Profile.create(user_id: self.id)
  end
```

Comment: okay thank you!! that helped. the line `profile = self.profile.create` gave me an `undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass` error. because the User model has a has_one relationship with the Profile model, it had to be `profile = self.create_profile`

Comment: Oops, sorry.. fixed it